# Regex numeric only and one decimal issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code that will make sure that it only accept 3 numbers before the decimal and 3 numbers after decimal and one decimal only.

There is one scenario that it will not work.

Example:

if I type 12.123 then go back and type 12w.123, it will accept the "w" and remove the last number 3. It know its related with the JavaScript split.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

```
$('.numeric-decimal-63').on('input', function (event) {             
    var val = $(this).val();        
    var regex1 = new RegExp(/^(\d{1,3}|\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3})$/g);

    var regex2 = regex1.test(val);      

    if (!regex2){

        $(this).val(val.slice(0,-1));
    }

});
```

Comment: `$(this).val(val.slice(0,-1));` this removes the last character, even if you type in the middle

Comment: @Tretiak are you trying to remove the unwanted `w` in the input?

Comment: yes I am. As the user type I only want numeric values and one decimal as well as only 3 digits before and after decimal point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).val(val.slice(0,-1));
```

Will remove the last key, so "123w1" it removes the "1". You may want to go back to the previous state:

```
var state="0";
$('.numeric-decimal-63').on('input', function (event) {             
var val = $(this).val();        
var regex1 = new RegExp(/^(\d{1,3}|\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3})$/g);
if (!regex1.test(val) && val!==""){
    $(this).val(state);
    return;
}
state=val;
});
```

Comment: Your solution wipes everything and set it to zero. I just want the character to be blank out.

Comment: in all fairness, I pu the var state="0" inside right before var val ..... because it would never get set otherwise. Am I wrong?

Comment: I just tried again this time, like you said to do and it works! Thank you. I am not sure how it gets set though.

Comment: ooops another issue, now it add a number as a default value in the text box. I cannot delete it.

Comment: it will not even compile now. It says "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable"

Comment: ok, everything works great but when you do a back space, it will not get ride of the first character. Then i have to high lite the first character and type over it. hard to explain. (character or numeric)

Comment: Wow. I do not know what to say. I would have never figure this out on my own. Everything seem to be working like it should. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I just discovered one more little issue. When you enter a character as the first one, it will keep the character.

Comment: i just type wwww... and it takes it.

Comment: where almost there. Can you took one last look?

Comment: ok, you did not respond but I just noticed you did more edit. Iit seems bulletproof so far! I just want to respond to thank you again and made sure other would know the last edit did the trick. Thank you Jonas!

Comment: @tretial youre welcome ;) . lets recycle these comments through deleting them, so that they dont waste SO space ressources...

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely positively never ever outright *block* user input. Here's why:

Let's say I'm typing away. <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>w</kbd> oops, finger slipped, no problem: <kbd>← Backspace</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> there. Now let's see... huh? Why does the textbox only show `12`? Where'd my `3` go?

Instead, allow the user to type whatever they wish, and only after input has finished (ie. on `change` event) should you validate the input and inform the user if it is non-compliant.

HTML5 does this for you:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="999.999" step="0.001" />
```

Comment: Number input doesn't even disallow letters in all browsers.  See FF.

Comment: @JenniferMichelle Have you tried submitting a form when there's non-numeric input in a `number` input?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were talking about correct-as-you-type (I had to read about 100 threads to figure out how to create my regex expressions).  There are some, though admittedly very few, cases where it's easier for user than seeing a bunch of validation errors.